# Swift Core Data Many to Many relationship handling with codegen as Manual/None

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, many-to-many

[image]

I Have a many to many relationship from WishList to Product. I made **codegen property as Manual/None**, so I have created respected classes as below.

```
class Product: NSManagedObject {
  struct constants {
    static let ID = "id"
    static let NAME = "name"
    static let DESCRIPTION = "description"
    static let wishLists = "shoppingLists"
  }
}

extension Product {
 @NSManaged public var id: Int64
 @NSManaged public var name: String
 @NSManaged public var desc: String
 @NSManaged public var wishLists: NSOrderedSet?
}

class WishList: NSManagedObject {
  struct constants {
    static let ID = "id"
    static let NAME = "name"
    static let PRODUCT = "products"
   }

  func addProducts(_values : NSMutableOrderedSet) {

  }
  func removeProducts(_values : NSMutableOrderedSet) {

  }

  func addProduct(_values : Product) {

  }
  func removeProduct(_values : Product) {

  }
}

extension WishList {
   @NSManaged public var id: Int64
   @NSManaged public var name: String
   @NSManaged public var products: NSOrderedSet?
}
```

What I need is, How do I implement convenience  methods to achieve below functionalities,   since core data does not create on behalf of me because I made codegen as Manual/None.

1. User can add a product into multiple wish lists
2. Each wishList can have multiple products.

Comment: Create another project and have Xcode generate the files for the same model, then copy them.

Comment: @Magnas thank u for the response, by doing this I can only copy the method signatures but I can't get the logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Codegen set to Manual/None, you're free to write your own implementation *or* let Xcode generate an appropriate subclass for you. (`Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass...`) All the helper methods would be readily available there. (assuming `NSOrderedSet`)

```
extension WishList {

    @objc(insertObject:inProductsAtIndex:)
    @NSManaged public func insertIntoProducts(_ value: Product, at idx: Int)

    @objc(removeObjectFromProductsAtIndex:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromProducts(at idx: Int)

    @objc(insertProducts:atIndexes:)
    @NSManaged public func insertIntoProduct(_ values: [Product], at indexes: NSIndexSet)

    @objc(removeProductsAtIndexes:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromProducts(at indexes: NSIndexSet)

    @objc(replaceObjectInProductsAtIndex:withObject:)
    @NSManaged public func replaceProducts(at idx: Int, with value: Product)

    @objc(replaceProductsAtIndexes:withProducts:)
    @NSManaged public func replaceProducts(at indexes: NSIndexSet, with values: [Product])

    @objc(addProductsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func addToProducts(_ value: Product)

    @objc(removeProductsObject:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromProducts(_ value: Product)

    @objc(addProducts:)
    @NSManaged public func addToProducts(_ values: NSOrderedSet)

    @objc(removeProducts:)
    @NSManaged public func removeFromProducts(_ values: NSOrderedSet)

}
```

...and vice-versa for `Product` and its `wishlists`.